# How do I introduce a delay between widget updates on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: canvas, tkinter, sleep

I'm new to Python. I'm using version 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
The below code is just a sample test for a larger script that I want to write to simulate an array of LEDs which can accept byte type values and reflect them in their output state. I chose to use Tkinter and a Canvas widget object to display and update the LEDs states. The problem that I have encountered is that I want to introduce a delay before an LED changes state (from off to on in this case).

What actually happens when I run this code is that the intended delay happens before the tkinter window, the canvas widget and the LED appear. When everything finally appears, the LED in already in its final state (on) so the OFF state was not even shown (or it was too fast). How can I have the window, canvas and the OFF LED display first, then have the 2 sec delay and finally have the LED change state from off to on? Thank you.

```
# LED simulation using tkinter canvas widget

from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('LED Simulation')

canvas = Canvas(width=640, height=480)
canvas.pack()

# create an LED object in the OFF state (dark red filled circle)
d7 = canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='dark red')

# wait in this OFF state for 2 secs
time.sleep(2)

# change the LED state from OFF to ON (light red filled circle)
canvas.itemconfig(d7, fill='light red')

# is this even needed?
canvas.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sleep()` will suspend the mainloop which means no updates will be made. Try using `after()` instead:

```
# LED simulation using tkinter canvas widget

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('LED Simulation')

canvas = Canvas(width=640, height=480)
canvas.pack()

# create an LED object in the OFF state (dark red filled circle)
d7 = canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='dark red')

# change the LED state from OFF to ON (light red filled circle)
def change_color():
    canvas.itemconfig(d7, fill='green')

# wait in this OFF state for 2 secs
root.after(1000, change_color) # Run after 1000 milliseconds

root.mainloop()
```

Changed the ON color to 'green' as my Python could not find the color light red'.

Comment: thank you for answering so quickly. Your solution worked like I wanted. Sorry about the'light red' it should have been just 'red'. Now I will try creating multiple LEDs and have them change state simultaneously after the delay!  I don't know how to mark this answer as 'accepted' so I am commenting here. This answers my question 100%.

Comment: Please start a new question instead of continuing on this one as the follow ups will be harder to find than a new question.

Comment: `after` will accept a function as parameter. When you give it `change_color(d6)` it runs the function once. Instead you can use lambda: `root.after(1000, lambda led=led: change_color(led))`. Then set the variable `led` to the desired object. The function will be run with the `led` parameter after 1000 ms.